Browser displays port on production Keycloak server running in Docker and Nginx Reverse Proxy
I use nginx on the main server (not in a container) with simple reverse proxy (not well versed on reverse proxies but this worked fine on my other containers so assumed it would here too...) with Keycloak(v23.0.1) running from a docker container.
What have I done wrong to have Keycloak displaying the port when I go to the admin page?
Below is what is displaying (note that the Keycloak site works as normal apart from displaying the port number in the browser)
By going to keycloak.tld.com I end up at https://keycloak.tld.com:58443/logon_url_path... (port added) site links perform as expected except with the port added...
IE: I type the base url for the site eg:keycloak.tld.com and site works as expected, except for the port being in the url... (I have another much older Keycloak server and it does not behave in this way (port in url))
The port is the right port, set both in the nginx config and in the docker run config...
Below is my nginx config:
server {
    server_name  keycloak.tld.com;

    access_log  /var/log/nginx/keycloak.access.log;
    error_log   /var/log/nginx/keycloak.error.log;

    location / {
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
      proxy_pass https://localhost:58443;
  }


    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.tld.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/keycloak.tld.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot

}

server {
    if ($host = keycloak.tld.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    server_name  keycloak.tld.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}

What have I missed?
SOLUTION
Had incorrect proxy_set_header settings, updated to below
    location / {
      proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $http_host;
      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
...
  }


"By going to keycloak.tld.com I end up at" - please properly explain, what steps are taking you there. That you entered keycloak.tld.com in your browser address bar, and it immediately redirected you into the admin area, is a bit unlikely, I suppose ... So, how exactly did you get there? Clicked any link, or submitted any form? If so, first of all check what the href/form action is pointing to - might be that your system generated a "faulty" URL to begin with.

@CBroe thanks for pointing out that it was not clear, have edited now...
